# MYSQL 8 Replication errors

Tags: mysql

Good Morning I have setup GTID replication between two mysql 8 databases they are for a Powerdns Setup When i make changes on the master I can only get one transaction to replicate then i am presented this error.

Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction '0b5041c0-8e71-11ec-a064-00155d14ef09:5' at master log binlog.000001, end_log_pos 2500. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.

If i run these commands

```
On master database:
mysql> reset master;
On slave database:
mysql> stop slave;
mysql> reset slave;
mysql> reset master;
mysql> start slave;
```

This clears the error and i am able to sync one more entry then i get presented with the above error again.

I used this guide to set it up
maybe i missed something in the setup.
https://medium.com/@michael_w_s/basic-setup-of-master-slave-gtid-replication-on-mysql-8-8f39ea29765c

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for taking time to reply

I have resolved this issue
My Main problem was i was importing all my data before setting up replication.

As soon as i setup replication first and then imported data all has been good.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, the error isn't actually shown there with that output, but rather will be in your error log, or one of the other locations it mentions in the message.

I found the root cause with:

```
tail /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Your log location may be different. In my case it was a permissions related error, but it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and found that I was using an older style variable in the my.cnf master file:

```
binlog-do-db = mydatabase
```

In the error log on the replica, I was getting errors because of another database I hadnt specified: 'my_other_database not found'. This implied that it was ignoring the variable and replicating ALL databases.

On MySQL8, the correct variable name to use is:

```
binlog_do_db = mydatabase
```

This solved the issue for me. Just ensure that your master database is listed in the table under "Binlog_Do_DB":

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB   | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000014 | 66373612 | mydatabase     |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+
```